# MuPDF Release Build Issue

Tags: android, pdf, ant, centos, mupdf

Can anyone please guide me how to compile release build of MUPDF , I am having serious problem when I run the mupdf release build on any android it crashes and throws the following error on logcat .

10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='globals' signature='J' in class Lcom/artifex/mupdfdemo/MuPDFCore; 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.openFile(Native Method) 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.(Unknown Source) 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.a(Unknown Source) 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5080) 10-28 23:59:33.410: E/AndroidRuntime(26648)

It works absolutely fine on debugging apk but when comes to signed release apk it crashes all the time . Please can any one help me in this regard .

Thank you.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem.But mine situation is a little bit different. The mupdf library was built into aar in release mode. It's fine when I built my app in debug mode. But it will crash when I built my app in release mode. Have you found a solution already?

Comment: It's related to ProGuard. It will be fine if I set runProguard to false. But after I add the classes should be skipped by proguard, the problem is still there. I'll post another question for that.

Comment: You can find the answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783067/proguard-issue-for-mupdf-library) post